# PHP someother user's account is opened

Tags: php, session, amazon-elb

I have found a strange issue. It has happened sometimes that I am logged in as user A but after doing certain activities when I am redirected to the new page, the logged in user changes. It is some other user's account access being given and I am logged in as user b now. I never ever opened that account in my system.

I am using aws elastic load balance along with php and mysql.

Let me know what all other info I can add as I don't see any reason why it would behave so

I am new in web development, so anything to take care to avoid such situations would be highly appreciated

Comment: Some code perhaps?

Comment: How do you keep track of which user you are? Are you using PHP's native session? Do you use custom session identifiers? Have you written your own cookie-related logic?

Comment: That sounds like a session issue. How are sessions stored (file, db, etc)? And how are sessions managed on the load balancer?

Comment: If it's a problem with the session files the a look at the ELB setting for "sticky sessions": http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html

Comment: @KarmanKertesz I am using "Sticky sessions" of ELB.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Yes, I am using PHP's native session and no custom session identifier is used.

Comment: @jfadich I am using ELB "sticky sessons" features and the sessions are stored natively by PHP in file I assume

Answer (score 0):

Are you switched to being a different user that you've never logged in with before?

If so then I'd assume this is purely a programming issue.

If you're either totally logged out or switched to a user you've previously tested then this is most likely a session issue when switching between different load balancers as the session data, I'm guessing is stored within the server process instead of shared in a database or in memory service.

Another solution

*edit*
Really sorry, I some how didn't see the comments on your question on the original post which state some of the same as above...

Regards

Liam